# Como cambiar la ruta donde guardar una imagen con Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Gracias a que contrate un hosting que no me deja acceder mas alla del public_html. Debo meter todo el proyecto alli, utilizando public_html como raiz. Entonces separe en una carpeta llamada laravel, todo el proyecto y deje suelto dentro de public_html todo lo q pertenecia a public

Cambiando un poco el index de esta forma

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comenzo a andar, tenia un problema de privilegios, por eso al principio no se veian las fotos, el tema es que al subir una imagen desde mi sitio, me cre1 el public/img dentro laravel y sube correctamente la imagen, pero la aloja alli y no en el img dentro de public_html

Un fragmento de codigo de como muestro una imagen

```
if($request->file('imagen'))
    {
        //Manipulacion de imagenes
        $file= $request->file('imagen');
        $nombre= 'emap_'.$evento->nombre.'-'.$fecha->toDateString().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path().'/img/eventos';
        $file->move($path,$nombre);

        $evento->imagen = $nombre;

    }
```

Tengo que lograr que me aloje correctamente a partir de mi raiz, que en mi caso es public_html/img/...

modificando el public_path() en app/Providers/AppServiceProvider de tal manera que el public baje un nivel al public_html seria la solucion

```
public function register()
{

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path().'/public_html'; // como moficar esta linea para que me imprima correctamente
    });
}
```

dejo mi sitio para mas facilidad de verificar el problema: emap.com.ar

Comment: No te puedo responder a tu mensaje directamente.
Revisando tu código, las fotos me dan error 403, revisa los permisos de las fotos sean 644 o 755 o 777.

Comment: corregi ese problemita. pero aun tengo el otro tema, igual ahora edito la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

// set the public path to this directory

$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Prueba a añadir este fragmento de código que debes cambiar en el fichero **index.php**

Fuente: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5

Comment: buena solucion no me di cuenta de poner __DIR__;  termine sacando el public_path() de cada $path. Por suerte eran solo 4. Pero esta es la solucion correcta